# Installing gem pg for PostgreSQL, openssl libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, openssl, pg

I am using RVM with ruby 2.0.0. When I try to install **pg** gem for PostgreSQL I get the following response.

**gem install pg**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/pg-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Tried to google for it, apparently the problem is with OpenSSL libraries, since in mkmf.log output is

```
have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -----------------$

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2$
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:32: warning: variable 'p' set but not used [-Wunused-but$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@O$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locati$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_certificate_file@O$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_by_id@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey@OPENSSL$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name@OPEN$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings@OPE$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_set_flags@OPENS$
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
```

Then I reinstalled ruby using OpenSSL directory specified in

```
openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/ssl
```

And still same problem.

Tried to intstall gem with **--with-pg-config** flag. Same problem.

Tried common workaround found on many websites

```
mv $rvm_path/usr/lib $rvm_path/usr/rvm_lib
gem install pg
mv $rvm_path/usr/rvm_lib $rvm_path/usr/lib
```

The error was different this time though.

**gem install pg**

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Assuming that it still tries to get **openssl.so** from Ruby catalogue - problem is with Ruby using wrong **openssl.so** file. But the fact is, that I've recompiled it with **--with-openssl-dir** flags.

Any suggestions on that? I am literally stuck for previous 10 hours trying every workaround I can find.

Comment: try this http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html to install openssl

Comment: Nick, It was not about the verification, it was about Ruby and Postgre using different OpenSSL libraries. Thanks for you help, I've found a solution.

Comment: rvm pkg install openssl

rvm reinstall 2.0.0

gem install pg should work, rely on rvm helping you manage your openssl/dependencies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the command used, we miss the double-dash (`--`) when reinstalling ruby:

```
openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/ssl
```

Comment: It's used as a alsmost-standard accepted way to say "Here we stop passing options to rvm" and those are then passed to the command rvm will launch